# How many pairs of natural numbers can be formed whose LCM will be $49000$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math

I'm stuck on this question.

First, I factorize $49000$.

$49000 = 2^3 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2$

I've just assumed the two numbers : $$P=(2^a \cdot 5^b \cdot 7^c)  \text{ and }  Q=(2^x \cdot 5^y \cdot 7^z)$$

Making the following pairs for :-

1) $$(a,x)=(0,3),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2)$$
Number of $(a,x)$ pairs is $7$

Similarly,

2) Number of $(b,y)$ pairs is $7$

3) Number of $(c,z)$ pairs is $5$

so the total number of $(P,Q)$ pairs which can be formed $= 7\cdot7\cdot5 = 245.$

But I have doubt that I have over-counted.

Comment: How does $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ work for $(a,x)$?

Comment: Thanks.I mistook and have edited.

Comment: Must P and Q be distinct or not? Also, is it ordered pairs or unordered pairs?

Comment: P and Q are not ordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is correct if you consider **ordered pairs**, that means if you want to count $(1,49000)$ and $(49000,1)$ as different pairs.

Since the LCM is obviously symmetric, one could naturally ask about the number of **unordered pairs**. The gut reaction would be to divide the above answer by 2, but that leads to problems as $245$ is odd.

The reason that approach doesn't work directly is that while the **$2$** different ordered pairs $(1,49000)$ and $(49000,1)$ just become one unordered pair, only the **$1$** ordered pair $(49000,49000)$ becomes the unordered pair $(49000,49000)$.

That means all the ordered pairs of the form $(x,x)$ become just one unordered pair, while the 2 ordered pairs $(x,y), (y,x)$ with $x\neq y$ become one unordered pair.

Since LCM$(x,x)=x$, the only ordered pair that applies to is actually $(49000,49000)$.

That means we have $1+\frac{245-1}2=123$ unordered pairs.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is correct if P and Q are not necessarily distinct and ordered.

If P and Q are distinct, then there are only $244$ pairs since you counted $49000$ twice.

If the pair is unordered then clearly you counted everything twice so there are only $1+\frac{244}{2}=123$ pairs.